# How do I target an element using CSS-in-JS?

Tags: css-in-js

I don't have access to the element I need to style and there are no class names or IDs on it. How do I target an HTML element using CSS-in-JS? For example:

```
svg path {
  fill: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have such a case I'm looking in the dev tools, elements tree tab and searching for a parent element with class or id which then I can use to wrap the element I need to select, for example:

```
<div class="parent">
  <svg />
</div>
```

Then you can select:

```
.parent svg path {
  fill: red;
}
```

However, if you don't have the parent and you want to style the svg with javascript then you can do as follows:

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg path')
svg.style.fill = 'red'
```

Keep in mind that this will target all SVG's in the project, if that's what you want then you're good if you want to style just this one SVG and there are more that you don't want to touch, then you will need to find a good parent to use and target the SVG inside that parent element, if there isn't close parent look for page ID or something of this sort. Let me know if this helps or I can help you further with that!